# Why does an img push down the text content next to it?

Tags: html, css

I have this bit of code:

```
<p><img src="img/icon.png" />View</p>
```

With the inclusion of that img tag, the text "view" is pushed down. Even if i try to give the p tag a line-height equal to the img height, it still looks off balance.

What am I missing?
jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/bLUL6/

Comment: you have to change the `vertical-align` of the image, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/bLUL6/4/

Comment: @KaeruCT why not post your comment as answer ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
img {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
​
```

[This blog](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/vertical-align/) has a detailed explanation of how `vertical-align` works with inline images.

Comment: Amazing, worked perfectly. I need to keep this one in mind. Thank you :)

Comment: It still doesn't answer the question "Why is this happening?"

Comment: @PavloMykhalov Added a link to a site with detailed explanation.